# Flutter - Persistant navigation bar not working properly

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, material-components-android

I am using persistant navigation bar in flutter but it is appearing on some pages & not appearing on the same pages.

actually i was facing an issue that when from other buttons i want to change the active tab. so i merged the drawer into the home page where I had persistant bar code. but i have fixed that issue

but the new issue occurred. i had a issue that how to change the appbar title i fixed that too using getx. I am changing the appbar title in init state of that page.

but then after that the navigation bar started disappearing I don't understand how to fix that issue and why is this being occurred...

**PERSISTANT NAVBAR CODE**

```
//rest code

  List<Widget> _buildScreens() {
    return [
      const DashboardScreen(),
      const Order(),
      const SetMpin(),
      const Recharge(),
      const Support(),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final NavigationController navigationController =
        Get.put(NavigationController());
    final cart = Provider.of<CartProvider>(context);
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Obx(() => Text(navigationController.name.value)),
// i amm here setting the app bar title dynamically
            actions: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => const CartList()));
                    },
                    child: Center(
                      child: badges.Badge(
                        badgeContent: Consumer<CartProvider>(
                          builder: ((context, value, child) {
                            return Text(
                              cart.getCounter().toString(),
                              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            );
                          }),
                        ),
                        child: const Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => const Profile()));
                      },
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.person)),
                ],
              ),
            ]),
        drawer: Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            children: <Widget>[
              ListTile(
                title: const Text('Home'),
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    controller.index = 0;
                    // WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                    //   final navigationController =
                    //       Get.find<NavigationController>();
                    //   navigationController.setName("Profile Details");
                    // });
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  });
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: const Text('Order'),
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    controller.index = 1; // Change the index to the desired tab
                    Navigator.pop(context); // Close the drawer
                  });
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: const Text('Wallet'),
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    controller.index = 2; // Change the index to the desired tab
                    Navigator.pop(context); // Close the drawer
                  });
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: const Text('Recharge'),
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    controller.index = 3; // Change the index to the desired tab
                    Navigator.pop(context); // Close the drawer
                  });
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: const Text('Support'),
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    controller.index = 4; // Change the index to the desired tab
                    Navigator.pop(context); // Close the drawer
                  });
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: PersistentTabView(
          context,
          controller: controller,
          screens: _buildScreens(),
          items: _navBarsItems(),
          confineInSafeArea: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          handleAndroidBackButtonPress: true,
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
          stateManagement: true,
          hideNavigationBarWhenKeyboardShows: true,
          decoration: NavBarDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            colorBehindNavBar: Colors.white,
          ),
          popAllScreensOnTapOfSelectedTab: true,
          popActionScreens: PopActionScreensType.all,
          navBarStyle: NavBarStyle.style1,
          onItemSelected: (index) {
            switch (index) {
              case 0:
                navigationController.setName("Dashboard");
                break;
              case 1:
                navigationController.setName("Orders List");
                break;
              case 2:
                navigationController.setName("Wallet");
                break;
              case 3:
                navigationController.setName("Recharges");
                break;
              case 4:
                navigationController.setName("Support");
                break;
              default:
                navigationController.setName("M-Mart");
            }
          },
        ));
  }
}
// rest code
```

SOME PAGE CODE

```
class _MyShopsListState extends State<MyShopsList> {
  List<Map> venderList = [];
  bool loading = true;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      final navigationController = Get.find<NavigationController>();
      navigationController.setName("Shop Lists");
    });
    CategoryServices.getVenderDetails(widget.serviceId.toInt())
        .then((response) {
      if (response['venderlist'] != null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < response['venderlist'].length; i++) {
          venderList.add(response['venderlist'][i]);
        }
      }
      loading = false;
      // setState(() {});
    });
  }
```

GETX CODE

```
class NavigationController extends GetxController {
  RxString name = "M-Mart".obs;
  void setName(String newName) {
    name.value = newName;
  }
}
```